# iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90701: "Missing entitlement?

Tags: ios, watchkit, itunes, healthkit, code-signing-entitlements

iOS 11 and Xcode 9.0 I have get following error when upload watch app on iTunes.

iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90701: "Missing entitlement. watchOS extension 'MyApp.app/Watch/iPhoneApp WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/iPhoneApp WatchKit Extension.appex' uses 'UIBackgroundModes' value 'workout-processing' without the required entitlement 'com.apple.developer.healthkit' signed into the bundle."

Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.

Comment: have you enabled HealthKit capability on the project cabilities in XCode?

Comment: Yes HealthKit is enabled on capability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve this issues. without enable health kit you have disable Workout processing on Background Modes.

Your application ->  Myapp WatchKit Extension -> Capabilities -> Background Modes

- Open your Capabilities
- Unchecking Workout processing from Background Modes
- Now upload watch app on iTunes store

[image]